# Spark : Aggregating based on a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file consisting of 3 fields (Emp_ids, Groups, Salaries)

- 100 A 430
- 101 A 500
- 201 B 300

I want to get result as

1) Group name and count(*)

2) Group name and max( salary)

```
val myfile = "/home/hduser/ScalaDemo/Salary.txt"
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Salary").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc=  new SparkContext( conf)
val sal= sc.textFile(myfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Scala DSL:

```
case class Data(empId: Int, group: String, salary: Int)
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(lst.map {v =>
   val arr = v.split(' ').map(_.trim())
   Data(arr(0).toInt, arr(1), arr(2).toInt)
  })
df.show()
+-----+-----+------+
|empId|group|salary|
+-----+-----+------+
|  100|    A|   430|
|  101|    A|   500|
|  201|    B|   300|
+-----+-----+------+

df.groupBy($"group").agg(count("*") as "count").show()
+-----+-----+
|group|count|
+-----+-----+
|    A|    2|
|    B|    1|
+-----+-----+


df.groupBy($"group").agg(max($"salary") as "maxSalary").show()
+-----+---------+
|group|maxSalary|
+-----+---------+
|    A|      500|
|    B|      300|
+-----+---------+
```

Or with plain SQL:

```
df.registerTempTable("salaries")

sqlContext.sql("select group, count(*) as count from salaries group by group").show()
+-----+-----+
|group|count|
+-----+-----+
|    A|    2|
|    B|    1|
+-----+-----+

sqlContext.sql("select group, max(salary) as maxSalary from salaries group by group").show()
+-----+---------+
|group|maxSalary|
+-----+---------+
|    A|      500|
|    B|      300|
+-----+---------+
```

While Spark SQL is recommended way to do such aggregations due to performance reasons, it can be easily done with RDD API:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(Data(100, "A", 430), Data(101, "A", 500), Data(201, "B", 300)))

rdd.map(v => (v.group, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect()
res0: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((B,1), (A,2))

rdd.map(v => (v.group, v.salary)).reduceByKey((s1, s2) => if (s1 > s2) s1 else s2).collect()
res1: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((B,300), (A,500))
```

Comment: I am trying to do this without Sql context .

Comment: Thank you. How to run the Spark SQL as  a batch file from command prompt or schedule it in hue ?

Comment: To run as a batch you should use spark-submit. For scheduling default option in Hadoop infrastructure is Oozie. That's the short answer, so it will be better to start new topic in new question. If your original question is answered, plz accept the answer.